# Consume WCF with SimpleInjector

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, simple-injector

Im still new to SimpleInjector and WCF in General

Is there any way to consume WCF using SimpleInjector?
Below is my WCF Code

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPassAuth
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Authenticate(string uid, string pass);
}

public class PassAuth : IPassAuth
{
    //   Implementations here...
}
```

Now The QUESTION is how can I consume it ASP.Net MVC using SimpleInjector? 
Do I still need to create an interface with its matching OperationContracts?
I've read the documentations [on WCF Integration Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/wcfintegration.html) but I can't seem to grasp the idea due.

Any simple code would greatly clear and help.

Answer (score 2):

The article you mention is about server side activation of wcf services, it doesn't apply to client side consuming. And yes, you need implementation of the class at the client side.

A simplest approach is to use the built-in factory that automatically creates client side proxies based on interfaces using reflection.

In your case

```
    BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();

    EndpointAddress myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://service/address");

    ChannelFactory<IPassAuth> myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IPassAuth>(myBinding, myEndpoint);

    // the CreateChannel automatically creates a instance
    // of a concrete client-side proxy class for given interface
    IPassAuth wcfClient = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
    string s = wcfClient.Authenticate( ... );
```

Another, more advanced option is to write a class that inherits from the `ClientBase`. With this approach you could possibly add custom extensions to the created class.

Comment: is this the same as calling from a RestApi.dll?

Comment: Sorry, never heard of RestApi.dll. Sounds like something to build or consume REST services but even googling doesn't help me identify what particular solution it is.